# apply force on scnnode without loosing it on collision

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to create some simple logic on scenekit but without luck so far.
I have a sphere and between two planes. The sphere as dynamic physic body and the two planes contains static physic body.
I'm applying force on the sphere towards one of the planes. on collision the sphere bounces from the plane to the opposite direction but it losses lots of the force. how can I make it to keep the force on collision. This is the viewDidLoadCode that is generated in xCode on Game template with my changes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = .omni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // retrieve the ship node
    let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sphere", recursively: true)!




    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene

    ship.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(x: 100,y: 0, z: 0), asImpulse: false)


    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = true

    // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

[the scn file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrUAk.png)

[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCE0O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the restitution property of the physicsbody.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514740-restitution

“This property simulates the “bounciness” of a body. A restitution of 1.0 means that the body loses no energy in a collision—for example, a ball dropped onto a flat surface will bounce back to the height it fell from. A restitution of 0.0 means the body does not bounce after a collision. A restitution of greater than 1.0 causes the body to gain energy in collisions. The default restitution is 0.5.”

Additionally you may want to reduce the .friction and .rollingFriction properties.